# the count method in python can not ignore the empty string

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,1,2,1,3,2],'y':[34,23,23,65,45,12,28],'z':['a','b','a','','a','c','b']})
df.groupby('x').z.count().reset_index()
```

```
  x  z
0  1  3
1  2  3
2  3  1
```

But this is what I don't want, the empty string should not be in the count, so what I want is

```
  x  z
0  1  3
1  2  2
2  3  1
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python the empty string is not considered null, you can replace it as null and do the same.

```
df['z']=df['z'].replace({'':np.NAN})
df.groupby('x').z.count().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.replace({'z':''},np.nan).groupby('x').z.count().reset_index()
    x   z
0   1   3
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

Or

```
df.replace({'z':''},np.nan).groupby('x',as_index=False).z.count()
```